# Avoid empty first slide with xsavebox in beamer

Tags: beamer, xetex, boxes, emptypage

The following code, where I want to define some saved boxes I refer to throughout the document, produces an empty slide before the title slide (compiled with `mklatex -pdfxe`, it works fine with `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xsavebox}

\begin{document}
\begin{xlrbox}{A}
  A
\end{xlrbox}%
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \theA
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I avoid the empty slide? I don't understand where that slide comes from either.

Comment: I do not get an empty slide when I compile your document on an updated TeXLive 2019 installation.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat ah, it only happens with xelatex. Try `latexmk -pdfxe`

Comment: `(reasons not to use xelatex)++`.  ;-)

Comment: Move the box creation to the same frame as title is. I mean, `\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\begin{xlrbox}{A}
  A
\end{xlrbox}
\end{frame}`

Comment: @Sigur right, that works, but then I always need to include the titleframe if I reference the box right? So it breaks `\includeonlyframes{current}`. My workaround is to use `\includeonlyframes{title,current}` but that's not nice :)

Comment: Sorry, for `xelatex` and `latex`+`dvips` (DVI-based workflows) this is the only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all workflows that involve DVI/XDVI, making a PDF XObject (e. g. through `xsavebox`) needs to happen on a document page. It is implemented through specials (`\special{ps: ...}` and `\special{pdf: ...}`) for these workflows.

To avoid the extra page with the `beamer` class, put `xlrbox`/`\xsbox` in a frame, as suggested by user Sigur.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xsavebox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{xlrbox}{A}
    A
  \end{xlrbox}%
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \theA
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```